# How to get ssh to automatically use a certain port for a specific server?

Tags: ssh

I use `ssh` to get into a specific server on a specific port as normal:

```
ssh -p <port_number> <server_name>
```

How do I configure ssh to automatically use the right port number for a specific server, so that I don't have to enter the `-p <port_number>` parameter? Note different servers I connect to will have different port numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file. For example:

```
Host bad.example.com
    Port 2222

Host *
    Port 22
```